# Solving systems of linear equations involving modulo

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151607/how-to-solve-these-equations) on Stack Overflow earlier and became curious about its mathematics. Basically, the question is how to solve systems of linear equations under modular arithmetic. The equation is as follows:
$(5X_1 + 6X_2 + 7X_3 + 8X_4) \mod 26 = 15$
$(4X_1 + 7X_2 + 4X_3 + 11X_4) \mod 26 = 17$
$(2X_1 + 6X_2 + 6X_3 + 2X_4) \mod 26 = 10$
$(9X_1 + 3X_2 + 1X_3 + 8X_4) \mod 26 = 18$

Clearly, this is just a system of simultaneous equations. If this just involved "normal" integers, I'd just set up an augmented matrix and row-reduce it to find the answer. Unfortunately this isn't so easy.

First, would it be correct to just say that we're solving this in $Z_{26}$ or am I misreading the notation? Also, am I correct in saying that $Z_{26}$ is *not* a finite field since 26 is neither prime nor a power of a prime?

I've read several other posts that talk about similar problems, such as:

- [how to solve linear equations involving modulo?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9370/how-to-solve-linear-equations-involving-modulo)
- [How to solve system of equations with mod?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203660/how-to-solve-system-of-equations-with-mod)

I've been having trouble finding a detailed walk-through on how to do this though. Is it possible to still row-reduce here somehow, or should I try something like Cramer's Rule? How do I do that?

There is, of course, an exceptionally dumb brute force way of solving this if you happen to be using a computer:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 25; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= 25; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l <= 25; l++)
            {
                int equation1 = (5 * i) + (6 * j) + (7 * k) + (8 * l);
                int equation2 = (4 * i) + (7 * j) + (4 * k) + (11 * l);
                int equation3 = (2 * i) + (6 * j) + (6 * k) + (2 * l);
                int equation4 = (9 * i) + (3 * i) + k + (8 * l);

                if (equation1 % 26 == 15 && equation2 % 26 == 17 && equation3 % 26 == 10 && equation4 % 26 == 18)
                {
                    string result = string.Format("i: {0} j: {1} k: {2} l: {3}{4}", i, j, k, l, Environment.NewLine);

                    File.AppendAllText(resultsFile, result);
                }
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Interestingly, this gives me the results
$x_1 = 23, x_2 = 11, x_3 = 24, x_4 = 20$
and
$x_1 = 23, x_2 = 24, x_3 = 24, x_4 = 7$
where $i = x_1, j = x_2, k = x_3, l = x_4$.

It seems odd to me that there should be 2 solutions here, since according to one of my favorite linear algebra textbooks (Robert A. Beezer's *A First Course in Linear Algebra*, which has the dual advantages of being both free and concise :)) [states](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-TSS.html) that "A system of linear equations has no solutions, a unique solution or infinitely many solutions." Did I mess something up in how I wrote this, or is it legitimately possible that systems of linear equations under modular arithmetic will have $1 < n < \infty$ solutions?

Just for clarification, I'm looking mostly for the mathematical (not programmatic) way of solving this. (The programmatic way of solving it is probably a better fit for Software Engineering SE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve this system by mod 13 and by mod 2. ($Z_{13}$ and $Z_2$ is a finite fields  )

Determinant of the matrix is -1024 => where is one solution in $Z_{13}$ (Use Gauss or Kramer to found it - it is (10, 11, 11, 7))

In $Z_2$:

$X_1 + X_3 = 1$

$X_2 + X_4 = 1$

0 = 0

$X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 0$

=>$X_1+ X_3 = 1 , X_2 = 1, X_4 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The statement

> A system of linear equations has no solutions, a unique solution, or infinitely many solutions

Is true; and, as mentioned, applies to **linear equations**. We may model this as a set of linear equations, but it's not a system, because one variable is restricted to a subset of $\Bbb R$ (namely, $\Bbb Z$). $a \equiv b \; (\mathrm{mod\;} x) $ implies there exists some $c$ such that $a - cx = b$. Thus, we apply this to your system of linear equations, and let this $c$ be denoted by $X_5$. Now, you have a system of $4$ equations in $5$ variables.

$$5X_1+6X_2+7X_3+8x_4-26X_5 = 15$$

$$4X_1+7X_2+4X_3+11x_4-26X_5 = 17$$

$$2X_1+6X_2+6X_3+2x_4-26X_5 = 10$$

$$9X_1+3X_2+1X_3+8x_4-26X_5 = 18$$

However, one of your variables is restricted to $\Bbb Z$.

This is all I have to say for now, and I will ponder a bit of this when I get my thoughts straight.

Comment: To clarify, does that mean that the mod means it's not actually linear?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I apologize; this is a system of linear equations

Comment: @EJoshuaS Looks like I can't seem to make up my mind! :P It is **not** a system of linear equation in $\Bbb R^n$, because the variable we chose as a difference between our numbers is restricted to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: There should be a new variable for each equation.