# Multivariable linear congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I would like to compute the solution space of the following system of linear congruences

$\begin{alignat*}{2}
a_{11}x_1+&\ldots&a_{1n}x_n&\equiv& b_1&\pmod{n}\\
a_{21}x_1+&\ldots&a_{2n}x_n&\equiv& b_2&\pmod{n}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n1}x_1+&\ldots&a_{nn}x_n&\equiv& b_n&\pmod{n}
\end{alignat*}$

Here $n$ need not be a prime and there is no restriction on $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s.

While searching in the literature, I came across [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5114.pdf) article by Knill. I also encountered a few posts on math.SE, for example:

- [how to solve linear equations involving modulo?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9370/how-to-solve-linear-equations-involving-modulo)
- [Solving systems of linear equations involving modulo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059101/solving-systems-of-linear-equations-involving-modulo)

In fact as mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059101/solving-systems-of-linear-equations-involving-modulo) post, I had also written a programme using brute force.

I would like to know whether there is any efficient algorithm (like CRT or some linear algebra methods) or any implementation in some CAS is available?